# How can I solve this dplyr select last_col error?

Tags: r, dplyr

on the following R query, why I get the error message?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(c(1:3), last_col(5:0))

>>> Result error message
> Error in `select()`:
> ! Problem while evaluating `last_col(5:0)`.
```

I've been using same query well on my own, but it doesn't work on another laptop. If i erase last_col() function, it is working. Maybe last_col function is the problem, but i can find any solution. What should i do?

it is working :

```
df %>%
    select(c(1:3))
```

and it didn't work :

```
df %>%
    dplyr::select(c(1:3), last_col(5:0))
```

Comment: I think you need `last_col(5)` meaning select 1,2,3 ... and up to 5th column from last

Answer (score 2):

Your error message is caused by improper use of `last_col()`. The `:` operator shouldn't be used within `last_col()`, but `last_col()` can be used with `select` and the `:` operator. Can you tell us which columns exactly you're trying to select?

More information on `last_col()` here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html

EDIT: Added package versions and reproduced error message.

```
#library(pak)
#pak::pak("tidyverse/tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
packageVersion("tidyverse")
#> [1] '1.3.2'
packageVersion("tidyselect")
#> [1] '1.2.0'

data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% names()
#>  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
#> [11] "carb"

mtcars %>% select(c(1:3), last_col(5:0)) %>% names()
#> Error in `select()`:
#> ! Problem while evaluating `last_col(5:0)`.

mtcars %>% select(c(1:3), last_col(5)) %>% names()
#> [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "wt"

mtcars %>% select(1:last_col(5)) %>% names()
#> [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"

mtcars %>% select(last_col(5)) %>% names()
#> [1] "wt"

mtcars %>% select(last_col()) %>% names()
#> [1] "carb"
Created on 2022-11-02 with reprex v2.0.2
```

Comment: Weird, `mtcars %>% select(c(1:3), last_col(5:0))` works on my machine. It’s clearly an undocumented use though, which would explain the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @zephryl interesting, I edited my post to include package versions and the reproduced error message, AFAIK I have the most updated versions of `tidyverse` and `tidyselect`.

Comment: sorry for late. and i solved it with this query : `last_col(5):last_col(0)`. It's really weired some things work and some thing don't.